# How to correctly define JSDoc for Node.js modules in extends/inherit case on mixins

Tags: javascript, node.js, phpstorm, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I've got three Node.js modules. One called `user` gets inherits from `base` module. The `handler` module interacts with an instance of `user`:

#### Base module - which is getting inherit:

```
/**
 * Base module
 */
'use strict';
const _ = require("underscore");

module.exports = {

    name: "base",

    /**
     * Extent object helper
     */
    extend: function(child) {
        return _.extend({}, this, child);
    },

    /**
     * Delegate event method
     */
    delegate: function () {
      //some delegate event
    }
};
```

#### User module - like a model:

```
/**
 * User module
 */
'use strict';
const BaseController = require("./base");

module.exports = BaseController.extend({

    name: "user",

    /**
     * Init function
     */
    init: function() {
    }
});
```

#### Handler - like a controller:

```
/**
 * Handler module
 */
'use strict';
const user = require("./user");

module.exports = {

    name: "handler",

    /**
     * Some action
     */
    someAction: function() {
      user.delegate(); // <-- delegate() is not known as a method of "user"
    }
};
```

The important part in the codes is marked with an comment `// <-- delegate() is not known as a method of "user"` because its inherits by `base` module. I realy like to know how to create a full JSDoc on this modules to make my IDE supporting autocompletion on my code, expecially for `user.delegate()`. A answer which provides all must-have JSDoc-Blocks whould be a great deal!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [`@inheritdoc`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-inheritdoc.html) directive:

```js
/**
 * @classdesc Abstract class representing a network connection.
 * @class
 */
function Connection() {}

/**
 * Open the connection.
 */
Connection.prototype.open = function() {
    // ...
};


/**
 * @classdesc Class representing a socket connection.
 * @class
 * @augments Connection
 */
function Socket() {}

/** @inheritdoc */
Socket.prototype.open = function() {
    // ...
};
```

---

So, **for your specific case**,

```js
/**
 * @class
 * @augments Base
**/
module.exports = {
  name: 'User'
};
```

Comment: Could you explain how your prototyping answer does match with the mixings object in my question? An answer with docblocks based on my codes is expected. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't correctly understand your comment, but, for example, **because `delegate` is being implemented by `Base`, then, also `User` (since it extends `Base`) inherits that method.

Comment: Yea, this will work fine for your prototype objects but I'm using mixins with inherited/extended mixins objects. I may do not fully understand your answer. Could you add the necessary DocBlocks into your answer based on "all" my codes? That would help me.